# Possible to make live template that makes kebab case method names?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

What I want to do is, Command+J -> select my live template and start typing, like "a user has a profile". And it would spit out:

```php
/** @test */
public function a_user_has_a_profile()
{

}
```

Here's what I got, which isn't ideal, but works:

```
/** @test */
public function $NAME$$NAMETOO$()
{
    $END$
}
```

Variables are set to:
`NAMETOO`: `spacesToUnderscores(NAME)`

Now, if I type a sentence, hit TAB, then shift+tab, then delete...I get what I want. Obviously, this is too much work. I may as well type the underscores. Thing is, I hate typing with underscores instead of spaces. :)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there's no more elegant solution for that. Please vote for the request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6613

Comment: OMG that request is from EIGHT years ago. I have a love/hate relationship with jetbrains. :P